Automatic expression generation in Dbeaver for the columns added after tablename
I am using dbeaver and whenever i try to use columns with alias or with table name, it suddenly generates a text automatically which is very annoying.
this is the expression:
SCHEMANAME.FN_PISYSIDS(:IN_CHIAVE, :IN_NUMERO)
so whenever i do tablename.columnName or alias.columnName this expression is generated.
I have entered inside this function that replaces my columns, and it is like this (but i dont think the content of the function would be the problem).
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SCHEMANAME.fn_pisysids(in_chiave IN NUMBER, in_numero IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS 
    w_return NUMBER(18);
BEGIN 
    UPDATE SCHEMANAME.PISysIDS 
    SET idNext = idNext + in_numero 
    WHERE idChiave = in_chiave;

    BEGIN 
        SELECT idNext
        INTO w_return
        FROM SCHEMANAME.PISysIDS 
        WHERE idChiave = in_chiave;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
            w_return := NULL;
    END;    
    COMMIT;
    RETURN(w_return); 
END;

Searching google i have not found similar problem.
I have entered inside this function that replaces my columns, and it is like this (but i dont think the content of the function would be the problem). Searching google i have not found similar problem. I tried to toggle off the word completions but then i dont get suggestions.
I have searched on google but did not find a similar question. I also tried to toggle off the code completion in the DBeaver setting but the problem persists... it does not even suggest me first. it replaces what i wrote with copies of this expression for any table name or alias name.
I found another question on StackOverflow in which it suggested me as similar question, but there the problem was that table alias was added automatically, which is totally different from my case. I don't have table alias, but a function that happens to be in the database that is pasted automatically whenever i try to recall a column of a table.
